# How to use @package & @subpackage in phpdoc?

Tags: php, phpdoc

I'm wondering how I should use @package & @subpackage for class doc.

let say I've the following class

```
class My_Controller_Action_Helper_MyHelperAction extends Foo_Bar {}
```

Should it be:

```
@category    My
@package     Controller
@subpackage  Action_Helper
```

or

```
@category    My
@package     Controller
@subpackage  Action_Helper_MyHelperAction
```

or

```
@category    My
@package     Controller_Action
@subpackage  MyHelperAction
```

or

```
@category   My
@package    My_Controller_Action
@subpackage MyHelperAction
```

What if use namespace instead of '_'?

Comment: According to the website phpdoc.org, about category and subpackage: "This tag is considered deprecated and may be removed in a future version of phpDocumentor. It is recommended to use the @package tag’s ability to provide multiple levels."

Answer (score 8):

First: If you use "_" or "\" (the namespace separator) should not influence your decision, how you annotate your classes. The underscore "_" comes from a pre-namespace age and "acts like" the namespace separator, except that it not create any namespaces. So "My_Controller_Action" should be treated as "Action" in "My_Controller".

However, how you use `@package` and/or `@subpackage` is really your decision. For example I dont use `@category` at all and `@subpackage` is everything after the "second" namespace. Let me explain: I follow the PSR-0 standard, where a package is structured into `\<Vendorname>\<packagename>\<subpackage>\...` (or "_" instead of "\", depending on the version). Then `@package <vendorname>.<package>` and `@subpackage <subpackage>`.

Conclusion: Its up to you :) A documentor may gerenate different structures of your code, depending on the tags you use and how you use them. Just try it out.

Answer (score 4):

If you've came across this answer in 2020, both `@category` and `@subpackage` tags are considered deprecated, so please don't use them anymore.

Instead of that, you should use [**@package**](https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/package.html) to provide the required logical sub-division.

According to https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/category.html and https://docs.phpdoc.org/latest/guide/references/phpdoc/tags/subpackage.html :

> **Important** This tag is considered deprecated and may be removed in a
> future version of phpDocumentor. It is recommended to use the @package
> tag’s ability to provide multiple levels.

> **Important** This tag is considered deprecated and may be removed in a
> future version of phpDocumentor. It is recommended to use the @package
> tag’s ability to provide multiple levels.

Answer (score 2):

i use @package for the name of the package this file belongs to... surprise :) eg if its a plugin called xyz the @package for all files that belong in that package.

for doxygen (which i use) there is no such thing as a @subpackage although you can make your own. eg: http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/commands.html

For doxygen you can use something like @package my.awesome.package which breaks it down in to 'sub packages'

You can really use it for anything as long as it makes sense and is consistent. first decide what you want to use and then look at the recommendations / docs for that application as they are all different